# No active Drillbit endpoint found from ZooKeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-drill

I am currently working with a simple project to query the messages from Apache Kafka topic using Apache Drill. And now I am encountering an error when running the Apache Drill cluster when running this command.

`sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=localhost:2181"`

And the error that I encountered is:

`No active Drillbit endpoint found from ZooKeeper. Check connection parameters`

I am using the single cluster instance of ZooKeeper that came from Apache Kafka.

Can anyone help me with this problem? Is it ok to use the Zookeeper from Apache Kafka installation with Drill?

Answer (score 0):

`sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=localhost:2181"` command only connects to running DrillBit. If you have Drill running in distributed mode, please replace `localhost` with the correct IP address of the node, where Zookeeper is running and update port if needed.

If you want to start Drill in embedded mode, you may try running `drill-embedded.bat` or `sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local"` command.

For more details please refer to https://drill.apache.org/docs/starting-drill-on-windows/.